# Bootstrap Table Styling w/ Vertical Column Text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to reproduce a static image in html/css/bootstrap3 and I am having a hard time getting my column correct.

**Here is the end result I am going for:**

[image]

I would say this would be 5 columns, 1 row. The first column being a very small width with vertical text?

I have added all of the columns to my table but after I rotate the first column text, I am unable to re-size the column width correctly.

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered tb">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3" class="titleColumn"><span class="positionTitle">Specialist (19)</span></th>
    <td class="dotted">Position 1 <br /> Position 2 <br /> Position 3</td>
    <td class="dotted">Position 4 <br /> Position 5 <br /> Position 6</td>
    <td class="dotted">Position 7 <br /> Position 8 <br /> Position 9</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.dotted {
  border: dotted 3px #000000;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.positionTitle {
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* IE */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Opera */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  float: left;
}

.titleColumn {
 background-color: red;
 color: white;
}

.tb{
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
}
```

Here is where I am at on my fiddle:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/f1tack03/3/

1. Is there a better way to reproduce this than using a `table`?
2. How can I get the first column to look like my expected end result?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to adjust the way you position your `<th>` Add relative and absolute positioning.

```
.positionTitle {
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* IE */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Opera */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.titleColumn {
 background-color: red;
 color: white;
 position: relative;
}
```